# Type of factoring for $2x^2 +7xy + 3y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

This may sound simple (and I guess it is), but what is the technique employed to factor the expression below? Also, are there good resources online that you would know where one could practice it?

$$2x^2 +7xy + 3y^2$$

Thank you.

Comment: Splitting apart the middle term into $6xy$ and $xy$ followed by factoring is the simplest way.

Comment: @KM101 thank you but that wasn't my question. Could you state that factoring technique's name?

Comment: @bru1987 Completing the square.

Comment: With quadratics, that technique is usually called the "$ac$ method." Usually it's done with one variable only, but throwing in $y$ doesn't really change anything.

Comment: It's $(\color{blue}{2\xi^2+7\xi+3})y^2$ where $\xi=x/y$; you may be more familiar with factoring $\color{blue}{2\xi^2+7\xi+3}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Gotta love homogenizing polynomials. I still have nightmares about high dimensional projective spaces.

Comment: I should add that factoring of such an item is possible if and only if the discriminant is a square. This is the same "discriminant" as in the Quadratic Formula, namely $B^2 - 4 AC.$ In particular, when the discriminant is exactly zero, the item is itself a square, possibly times a constant. So, $3 x^2 - 42 xy + 147 y^2 $ has discriminant $42^2 - 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 147 = 1764-1764=0,$ a factoring leads to $3 (x-7y)^2. $   I guess an ingredient that should be emphasized is that of first factoring out the largest common factor of the three coefficients

Answer (score 1):

Quadratics of the form $ax^2+bx+c$ can be factored using the "ac method". The product of $a$ and $c$ is factored and the factors are summed to get $b$.

In your case:

$2x^2+7xy+3y^2=2x^2+xy+6xy+3y^2=(2x+y)(x+3y)$

Comment: I noticed that we should probably emphasize pulling out the gcd of the coefficients, in case we are given $10 x^2 + 35 xy + 15 y^2$

Comment: yes, good point